# Criar dinamicamente card css com jquery

Tags: html, jquery, json

Estou com seguinte problema ,preciso criar tela de filtros aonde estou usando card como formar de apresentacao para meus filtros , como esse aqui :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem meu problema [e que o filtro diciplina esta repetindo mais de uma vez ,quero remover as diciplinas duplicadas, cogido do html e jquery:

```
<div class="row" id="cardDiciplina">
<div class="column">
    <div class="card" id="nameDiciplinaCard">
        <h3>Introdução à Biologia</h3>
        <p>Carboidratos e Lipídios</p>
        <p>Proteínas e Atividade Enzimática</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="card">
        <h3>Bioquímica</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="card">
        <h3>acidos nucleicos</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="card">
        <h3>tipos de celular</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
        if (allInformation.length > 0) {
            $(allInformation).each(function (iRec, oRec) {



                if (nameMatter != oRec.nameMatterPrincipal)
                {
                    var nameDiciplinaMateria = ' <h1>' + oRec.nameMatterPrincipal + '</h1>';

                    $('#matterDiv').html(nameDiciplinaMateria);
                }
                //console.log(cont);

                //console.log(oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID);


                //console.log($('#nameDiciplinaCard').text());

                var a = '#nameDiciplinaCard' + oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID +'';

                console.log(a);
                ////var b = $(a).text();
                ////consolo.log(b);
                //if ($('#nameDiciplinaCard' + oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID+'').text() != a) {
                //    var p = '<div class="column"><div class="card" id="nameDiciplinaCard' + oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID+'"><h3>' + oRec.nomeAssuntoDiciplina + '</h3></div></div>'
                //    $('#cardDiciplina').append(p);
                //}


                if ($('#nameDiciplinaCard').val() != oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID)
                {

                    var html = '<div class="column"><div class="card" id="nameDiciplinaCard' + oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID + '" value=' + oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID+'><h3>' + oRec.nomeAssuntoDiciplina + '</h3></div></div>'
                    $('#cardDiciplina').append(html);


                }
```

Esse sao os dados do json que esta vindo da aplicação :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

solução que encontrei para esse problema foi em cada div criar um id dinamico :

```
   var diciplinaDiv = '#nameDiciplinaCard' + oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID + '';
```

Assim eu consigo verifica com jquery se minha div ja foi criar ,caso ela ainda nao existe eu crio dinamicamente o card como no codigo a seguir :

```
   var $myDiv = $(diciplinaDiv);
   
     if (!$myDiv.length) {
        var html = '<div class="column"><div class="card" id="nameDiciplinaCard' + oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID + '" value=' + oRec.diciplinaAssuntoPrincipal_ID + '><h3>' + oRec.nomeAssuntoDiciplina + '</h3></div></div>'
                    $('#cardDiciplina').append(html);
             

     }
```

Assim eu evito duplicamento.